# Xubuntu 16.04 doesn't show mp3 thumbnails (album art picture) - the rest of the thumbnails are ok!

Tags: xfce, thumbnails

I have xubuntu 16.04 and mp3 thumbnails don't work.
I already deleted .thumbnails and changed permission for thumbnails folder and didn't seem to solve the problem.help please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Thunar is showing you OTHER kinds of thumbnails, like for jpegs for example, since you specify mp3s. Correct me if that's wrong.

Quoting Toz (who is an astute chap who posts at Ubuntuforums frequently) posting on the Arch forum 2 months ago here in post 7:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=223000

> You can get tumbler to generate audio thumbnails natively on Xfce by
>   manually building it (ABS) with the following two proposed patches:
>
> - https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=6360
> - https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=6348

That will be a wee bit of work, but shouldn't take you more than a couple of hours to take in some of the tutorials all over the net about how to build software from sources and apply patches, and then do it. I haven't tried it myself, because I switched from Thunar to Spacefm about a year ago and I always use the details view anyway. But if Toz says it works, I'm sure it does. And that would be much better than switching to Nautilus. Custom actions in Nautilus are a PITA compared to Thunar. Nautilus is also a resource hog.

If you don't want to fool with patches, you might want to try `beets` which is in the repo. I'm NOT certain it can do this, but it thumbnails SOME audio files at least, and you might be interested in its other features.

And, if nothing else here is, not quite a work-around, but a sort of substitute you might find less painful than switching file managers. It will act recursively on a directory tree, extract the pictures embedded in mp3s, if any, making a copy in the same directory with the mp3, renamed by prefixing the mp3's name. If there is more than one, it will give them unique names. It should avoid making duplicate pictures if you already have the same picture for that mp3. So you can just run it again when you add mp3s to the directory. So, if you sort alphabetically, at least you have pictures extracted from the mp3 appearing adjacent to it. Not the same thing you asked for, but somewhat related & maybe better than nothing. It will also make a list in ~/ of mp3s that don't have any embedded pictures, so you can go hunt for some to fix them with. You will need the package `eyed3` which is in the repo.

2 scripts. Store them in the same directory. One uses the other. 2 valid syntaxes:

Either:

mp3s-get_images_for.sh directory_where_the_mp3s_are

or just:

mp3s-get_images_for.sh

In the latter case it will ask for the directory.

First script:

https://pastebin.com/raw/iMK8vAvy

I suggest naming it mp3s-get_images_for.sh

2nd script (called by the first on each mp3 file):

https://pastebin.com/raw/Js5uHpEg

This MUST be named

mp3s-get_images_for-make_1_img.sh

and kept in the same directory with the first one. You can change those things of course, but you'd have to edit the first script to allow for the changes.

One last comment: If you try the tumbler approach, I'd be interested how it works for you.